# How to take CMDeviceMotion updates in multiple handlers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cmmotionmanager

Apple says: You should only create a single instance of CMMotionManager to get accurate data.

What if I want to start the device motion updates when the app starts and then take the updatesToQueue at multiple places.

Scenario is something like this:

App starts
 - Start device motion updates without handler

ClassA
 - Start device motion updates to queue at a particular time.

ClassB
- Start device motion updates to queue at a particular time.

Stop device motion updates when required.

Comment: What about using a Singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `CMMotionManager` with a handler that posts notifications (see [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)). Your other classes can then listen for that notification when needed.